# Return content of a local php file with params

Tags: php, localhost, file-get-contents, vps

I have a VPS with multiple domains. Now, one of those website is trying to get the output of another website which has a Piwik installation (open source analytics) on it.

Currently, I just use `file_get_contents('https://domain.com?param=something')`, which works fine, but the contents get send 'over the web', which I noticed when I changed some DNS settings and I couldn't get my content for a few hours.

Since everything is on the same server, is there a way I can access the local PHP-file (*with* the params), and return the content by using a file path such as `/home/admin/domain/..`? I know I can get the (literal) contents of a local file, but I can't pass the params and get the response I need, since the file doesn't get executed.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, then this command might help you:

`php -f /path/to/file.php param=something > output.html`

If you don't need to save the output of the command just omit the `> output.html` part.

There's a catch, though. By using `https://domain.com?param=something` you're passing a `GET` variable but with this command it's different; you have to extract the param from `$argv` ([Explanation here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)). Therefore if you're not able to adapt your code then this won't help - but as far as I can tell you can.

Comment: Thanks! Took me some time to figure everything out, but combined with `if (isset($argv)) parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);` at the top of the requested file (converting `$argv` to `$_GET`), it does the trick.

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to mention that you have to separate key from value manually when using `$argv`, glad you figured it though :)